# Xamarin Android Deep Link

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement deep link on  a xamarin android application, but when I click on test link by smartphone it opening browser and not application.

I added the AssetLinks.json file on the website (and it's correct) and this is the intent filter:

```
[Activity(Label = "Test", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, 
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable,
        Android.Content.Intent.ActionView
    },
    DataScheme = "https",
    DataHost = "live.test.it",
    DataPathPrefix = "/",
    AutoVerify = true)
 ]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

Is there a recent guide to how?

Comment: Does your app meet those [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking#android)?

Comment: Hi, I followed this guide https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html because firebase dynamic Links is no longer recommended...
I added assetlinks.json on the website and the android app console confirmed the verification of this link.

Comment: Try to remove `Android.Content.Intent.ActionView` of Categories.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT
unfortunately nothing changes